# How to cd into multiple directories, zip it (naming it after the directory name)?

Tags: bash, zip, 7zip

So I have a bash script that cds into a directory, executes a command and then exits and enters a new directory again:

```
for d in ./*/ ; do (cd "$d" && somecommand); done
```

From [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/171679).

Unfortunately I'm not sure how to zip up the directory it is in (maybe using something such as 7z). It was a long shot but I tried this command and it didn't work (I didn't expect the asterisk to take the name of the directory...but I hoped):

```
7z a -r *.zip
```

I don't suppose anyone has any suggestions?

Comment: Look up tar and gzip

Comment: Why do you want to go into the directory before zipping it?

Comment: you'd need to do the 7zip call in your subshell. you're cding in the subshell, so every time you exit that subshell (each loop iteration), that subshell's cd'd directory is lost.

Comment: Do you mean you want "somecommand" to be a command that zips up the directory, or do you mean you want to zip up the directory afterward?

Comment: @123 I'll have a look at those, maybe they'll do what I want :-). @ Tom They're language packs for an application and the application needs the zip files to be zipped from the root directory, if that makes an sense (so say you were to right click > extract here, the files would be strewn around the zipped file rather than being inside of a folder). Sorry if that explanation is a bit strange, wasn't sure how else to phrase it.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, the somecommand would be the command the zips the current directory it is in (with the zip taking the name of the current directory)

Comment: Can you offer an example of a before and after.  It is unclear what you want the end result to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `$d` contains the name of the directory (among other things):

```
for d in ./*/ ; do (
    cd "$d"
    dirname=${d%/} # remove trailing /
    dirname=${dirname##*/} # remove everything up to the last /
    7z a -r "$dirname".zip
)
done
```

I'm assuming that your `7z` command was correct.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you're looking for something like this:

```
for d in *; do
  test -d "$d" && zip -r "$d.zip" "$d"
done
```

That examines all files in the working directory whose names do not begin with '.' (`for d in *`).  For those that are directories (`test -d $d`) it zips the directory contents, recursively, as members of a directory.  The zip files are left in the original working directory (the parent of all the directories that get zipped), but they could as easily be put into the subdirectories.

Comment: If you changed the `*` to `*/`, you could avoid the `test`, although then I guess you'd have to do something similar to my answer to extract the substring. I'd also recommend quoting your usages of `$d`. If you made those changes, this would be the better option, as it avoids creating a new subshell for every directory found.

Comment: @TomFenech, yes, I chose `*` instead of `*/` exactly so as not to have to mangle the names afterward.  I think it's cleaner; objectively, it's more concise.  Good point about the quoting, though; I will edit my answer in that regard.